# Wordpress- W3 Total Cache minification problems >:(

Tags: wordpress, caching, minify

For some reason, despite anything i do, I can not get minification to work for the life of me...I am going insane...does anyone have any suggestions? I also tried WP Minify with no luck...maybe an issue with my server?

Thanks guys!

Comment: As is, your question is too vague to receive a meaningful and helpful response. Consider expanding your question with a more detailed description of what you have tried and where you think the problem lies. If at all possible provide sample code of the 'trouble spot.' in the minification process.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, W3TC is not really supported anymore; it hasn't been updated in over a year.

Try WP Super Cache with the WPSCMin minify plugin.; it's much more popular anyway. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/

You will probably see minor performance gains with "minify" anyway. Much more important is to reduce plugins, scripts and style sheets in your theme.

Comment: W3TC is being updated again. [Last update was April 4, 2014](http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)